# MySql - using and condition in Where class with order by taking long time

Tags: mysql, sql

We have MySql table with arround 10 million records

following my are columns in my table

**c_id, s_id, c_name, domain, log_type, log_time, level, message**

we have indexes on these columns

**c_id, s_id, domain, log_type, log_time**

I'm running following simple query , it's taking very long time approximately 5 min

```
SELECT
  c_id,
  s_id,
  c_name,
  l_time,
  l_type,
  m,
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(l_time) AS time
FROM
  stats.c_logs
WHERE
  domain='xxx' and
  log_type='E_O'
ORDER BY
  log_time DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

why it's taking so long time for results, when I removed one condition in where clause I'm getting fast results, but with and condition it's taking time

and I have seen if I remove order by, results are quick

if you want any more details I can provide here

Comment: Which condition slowed down?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The optimal index for your query is a composite index on:  `campaign_logs(domain, log_type, log_time)`.

Individual indexes on the columns will not be as effective.

Comment: I have individual indexes on domain and log_type columns, so why we are not getting advantage of index merge here. Is composite index is necessary in this case ??

Comment: @rams . . . A composite index is preferable in this case for best performance.  Indexes are only "required" to enforce uniqueness constraints (and hence for foreign key references).